# Keychain Error -25308 (errSecInteractionNotAllowed) in macOS WidgetKit extension

Tags: swift, macos, widgetkit

I have an app with a `WidgetKit` extension for iOS 14. The app's widget requires reading the user credential from the keychain before making a request to a server to load the content for the widget. I am using an abstract `KeychainPasswordItem` class ([a mirror of the code here, cannot find origin](https://gist.github.com/madcato/dc1199067b29570d8054186648c92dc1)) to access the keychain item. Keychain sharing is set for both the app and the widget.

On the iOS widget the keychain loads perfectly fine both in the app and the widget. However, on the macOS widget (under the exact same code) it gives me an error -25308 (errSecInteractionNotAllowed).

Anyone else have this problem?